# Why do dangling pointer deferences crash the program

Tags: c++, c, pointers, memory, memory-management

I have heard many times that dangling pointer de-references can crash the program, but I don't know why. Could anybody please explain this to me?

As my understanding, in C/C++, after we free a memory object `o` via pointer `p`, `p` becomes a dangling pointer that points to a semantically invalid memory address `addr`. Maybe later `addr` is reallocated to another memory object by the memory allocator. Whether this happens or not, the os will consider `addr` is still a legal address to access because the memory allocator only requests memory from os and never give memory back to os. So there should be no crash at all. Could anybody please tell me where my understanding is wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't complain about crashes. It's much worse if the program *doesn't* crash under these conditions.

Comment: What if the freed memory is subsequently given to an object that contains pointers? Now those pointers will get overwritten with (essentially) random data. Next time those pointers that have been overwritten are dereferenced... poof!

Comment: @Galik, I understand that it can crash the program indirectly because of data inconsistency. But I'd like to know how can the program crash immediately when the dangling pointer is dereferenced, what is the mechanism?

Comment: In my experience programs usually do not crash immediately after allocated memory that has been deallocated is accessed. However, in theory, the page the memory is mapped to in the virtual memory table could be given back to the OS and marked as illegal in the hardware registers causing a hardware exception.

Comment: @Galik, are you suggesting that only when the memory is returned to the OS could the crash happen? If we use an allocator that does not return memory back, then there won't be immediate crash at the use-after-free site, right?

Comment: As I said before crashes can happen when a pointer is corrupted. Also they can happen when someone tries to write too far out of bounds into unallocated memory. Signals like `segfault` and `general protection fault` are hardware signals that are generated by the *memory management unit* of the `CPU`. Allocators have nothing to do with that, it is down to the *C++ runtime system* when chunks of memory are passed back to the `OS` for invalidation. In theory that can happen as soon as you call `delete[]` but in practice I think that's rather unlikely.

Comment: There must be hundreds of questions on SO from people asking why they can continue to use pointers after they have deleted them without getting a crash/error.

Comment: @Galik, thanks for the explanation. Let's simplify the question. Say I have a program as follow,
int* p = (int*)malloc(1);
*p=100;
free(p);
*p=200;
is there any possibility in practice that this program will crash?

Comment: Of course it is *possible*. The `C++` standard takes no account of what happens to memory after `free()` is called. Compiler writers are free to do what they want. But I think it is very unlikely. I think most crashes come from pointers that were never allocated, pointers that are null, pointers that are accessed out-of-bounds and pointers that got corrupted. What you are talking about silently screws up the running of the program in unpredictable ways - until a pointer/index-value gets walked on.

Comment: @Galik, Thank you very much for the careful explanation. The answer provided by Anton Savin is a good example. My previous understanding is wrong, and the allocator does return memory to the OS.  Maybe it is because I didn't allocate memory large enough for the allocator to give back that I didn't successfully crash the program by use-after-free.

Answer (score 4):

> *Whether this happens or not, the os will consider addr is still a legal address to access*

No, that's not the case, rather exactly opposite. Once you `free()` the memory, whether it is actually deallocated or not, it is considered illegal to access (*or even attempt to `free()` again*).

As every illegal memory access causes invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), so does this and the side-effect is segmentation fault.

Comment: does the OS register this information somewhere? something like the "invalid address list"?

Comment: @HumamHelfawi This is handled by the memory allocator itself.

Comment: which is a part of the OS right? since C++ is a native language without a framwork or VM?

Comment: @HumamHelfawi If you mean to ask whether it will prevent you from accessing, it won't. It will simply invoke UB.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I'm still confused. Who crashes the program when deferencing a dangling pointer, the os or the memory allocator? I think you are suggesting the memory allocator is responsible for this. But how could the memory allocator insert a check each time a pointer is dereferenced?

Comment: @Hua See, as soon as you try to access a memory location which is _invalid_, SIGSEV signal is raised. That's it. Allocator is not doing any checks for that, whatsoever.

Comment: But the memory location cannot be invalid because the memory allocator never return memory to os, right?

Comment: @Hua how you can be so sure it _never returns_? What is it returned, and reallocated to some other process? You'll be overwriting the memory for some other process, right? So, simply don't do it. It is UB.

Comment: @SouravGhosh, as far as I remember, the memory allocator in linux does not return memory to the os due to performance consideration. Forgive my ignorance, what abbreviation is UB for?

Answer (score 1):

A dangling pointer can point to anything, sometimes the program may continue
because the value that it got seemed correct, this may propogate multiple times
until something seg faults or worse.

```
foo *bar = malloc(sizeof(foo));
void * dangling = &bar;
free(bar);
```

What does dangling now point to? Or return a stack allocated structure as a 
pointer ie

```
char * foo() {
  char string[10] = "Boom";
  return string;
}
```

Basically the program has no way to detect that the item being used is valid
until used and sometimes even when it's used it still does not detect it. Detections can happen as follows in order of severity...

1. Compiler spots a double free or that you're returning a reference to a stack allocated object. Or your trying to free an object that the it never actually allocated.
2. OS spots that you are trying to access memory that's allocated outside the process address space ie Access Violation / Segmentation Fault / Bus Error etc.
3. Your program starts behaving oddly and eventually goes bang or someone reboots your app or it runs out of memory etc.

Your allocator ie malloc in my case may allocate memory from regions ie pre allocated blocks of memory that it has the start and end address for. Any request to free a region outside one of these ranges is an error and you'll likely get a segmentation fault in this case. This is one error the allocator can detect, it cannot detect that you've taken a reference to an area of memory that has subsequently been deallocated ie is now garbage. You then try and use the garbage and mayhem ensues.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Harry.  In your last sentence, you said "sometimes even when it's used it still does not detect it", but what about other times? Who detect it, and who crashes the program? The memory allocator, or the os, or something else?

Comment: thanks. As I asked in the question, the address is always valid because the memory allocator never return memory to the os, so the memory access is always within the process address space. Let's do not talk about later program crash due to propagated data corruption. Is there any possibility that the program crash immediately when the dangling pointer is dereferenced?

Comment: @Hua, You're missing the point then. With a dangling reference the address is likely not valid ie it may point to an address that is outside the realms of possibility ie 10^50. This may be in a system call in which case the OS will terminate your program as being invalid.

Comment: maybe I didn't define dangling pointer clearly. By dangling pointer deference, I mean use-after-free. What resides in the dangling pointer should be a previously valid address allocated by the memory allocator, rather than arbitrary address that we make up by casting an int to a pointer.

Comment: The problem's still the same, what's being pointed to might be garbage. Malloc is not part of your program per se, ie it's not there to "detect" where you might do something you shouldn't. Double free is something a good compiler might detect, using a reference to something you've deallocated and that address has now been allocated to something else unimaginable as a pointer is not something I'm aware any C complier does today.

Answer (score 1):

Language rules about undefined behavior aside, freeing memory might very well return that memory to the OS. Either directly when free is called or later, when the OS runs out of memory itself and asks applications to return unused chunks.

Dangling pointers can also cause crashes indirectly when you are accidentally overwriting other data, like the length of an array or the function's return address

Answer (score 0):

There's no guarantee the allocator doesn't return the memory to the OS, as well as any other guarantee on undefined behavior.

As I understand an answer satisfying you should contain an example of a code where dereferencing a dangling pointer immediately crashes the program. So here's an example which crashes (here and now) on Linux:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int* arr = new int[1000000];
    delete[] arr;
    std::cout << *arr << std::endl;
}
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc031b6bdb9d0570)

Comment: thanks a lot. This is what I'm looking for. So my previous understanding about the allocator is wrong. Thanks.